# How to do full codebase code coverage scan using azurepipelines-coverage.yml

Tags: code-coverage, .net-5, azure-devops-pipelines

**Reference**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/codecoverage-yaml-samples

The links above, only talk about diff coverage as part of Pull request. My questions are as follows:

**1**. How can we configure YAML to do full coverage instead of differencial coverage and produce the output in PR

**2**. When diff coverage is run, it is even considering files where [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] is mentioned as attributes. Do we have any settings for this to be excluded from target percentage?